# How can I save a stored procedure which contains errors in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to save a stored procedure which contains errors according to SQL  Server.

This is the procedure code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [Product].[JewelSearch]
    @JewelItem bigint,
    @JewelType nvarchar(50),
    @JewelMate nvarchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Product.@JewelType 
    WHERE Material = @JewelMate OR Item# = @JewelItem; 
END
```

The problem is that I have a `Product` schema, and I am taking the table name from my main application and saving it in `@JewelType` and in each search in main application the table name must be changed and each time their will be a different table name in `@JewelType`.

According to me the query is perfect but SQL Server does not allow me to execute it and save it. Is there a way that I can forcibly save this stored procedure? Hope you understand my question please help me if possible.

Comment: You can't have a dynamic table name in SQL Server. For that you would need to go the route of dynamic SQL. Read this before you do that though. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server : dynamic query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456441/sql-server-dynamic-query)

Comment: You should be searching for how to run a dynamic query in SQL Server, not how to save a stored procedure with errors.

Comment: And read up on SQL injection.

Comment: or use an ORM like NHibernate with discriminators to determine which child table to query.

Comment: and _please_ next time... post the actual error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is SQL Server, something like this should work

```
Create PROCEDURE [Product].[JewelSearch]

@JewelItem bigint,
@JewelType nvarchar(50),
@JewelMate nvarchar(50),
@SQL nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @SQL = 'Select * From Product.'+@JewelType+' where Material = '+@JewelMate+' OR Item# = '+CAST(@JewelItem as nvarchar(50))+'; '


EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

This is untested as I am on my Mac, but you get the idea.

If you are going to use this, be aware of the dangers of dynamic SQL in relation to SQL Injection.

[SQL Injection with Dynamic SQL - MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx)